# Once I add this method, I get a null pointer

Tags: java

Null Pointer Error

```
public int fromRoman(String romanChar)
{   
    int i = 0;
    int total = 0;    
    while (i < romanChar.length()) {                   <----------- THIS LINE
```

Any idea what this can tell me about how I could go about solving?

I know that fromRoman generally works as when I take out the method in question, it spits out an integer that I can display.  But when I add this method

```
public double getTotal(String whattodo) {

    int number1 = fromRoman(num1);
    int number2 = fromRoman(num2);

    if (whattodo == "*") 
    {
        return (number1 * number2);
    }
    else if (whattodo == "+") 
    {
        return (number1 + number2);
    }

    else if (whattodo == "/") 
    {
        return (number1 / number2);
    }

    else if (whattodo == "-") 
    {            
        return (number1 - number2);
    }

    else 
    {
        throw new NumberFormatException("There is no operation present.");
    }
```

As well as this in my run method I get a null pointer at the line previously indicated.

```
double total = getTotal(operator);
```

Comment: You're passing it a null argument. Figure out where the argument is coming from and why it's null.

Comment: `romanChar` is `null`, 100%.

Comment: What is num1 and num2 ?

Comment: Is num1 and num2 initialized

Comment: You should read [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone.  
num 1 and num 2 are in my constructor as 
String num 1 = new String(); and same for num 2 

Thanks PakkuDon, I am reading through there but it seems that the general suggestion would be to use 

whattodo.equals("+") and so forth?

Comment: You must compare strings with `equals` method.

Comment: It seems as is changing the method in question's string comparison method had avoided the null exception error.  Now I have a new beast to conquer. Thanks all.

Comment: Then I initialized num1 and num2 inside the method and it all worked out gravy.  Thanks so much everyone for taking a minute or two to help me out.  Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters `num1` and `num2` should be not `null` to parse their, otherwise it throws n `NullPointerException`.

You should instantiate their before calling of `fromRoman` function.

Comment: So now the method works by using the .equals comparison for strings, but I keep getting a 0 for an answer.  When you say instantiate you mean

something like String num1 = new String();

Comment: Good Stuff....this helped a lot, and once I changed the string comparison method as PakkuDon mentioned and then I instantiated inside the method before the call as you said....IT WORKED!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Thank you very very much for your help.  I truly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `romanChar` is not **null** before starting accessing it in the `while-loop`. Something like this:

```
public int fromRoman(String romanChar) {
    if (romanChar == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    int i = 0;
    int total = 0;
    // continue here
```

Comment: I don't get the null error until after I add that second method in, So i was assuming it had something to do with that method returning a null somehow?!  Not too sure, going to change how I am comparing the strings in the getTotal method to see if that helps.

Comment: Got it squared away.  Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

if you pass num1 and num2 as null that the only reason its throw nullPointerException so make sure values passed to the fromRoman() method isn't null if it null return back otherwise perform all the operation ..

```
public int fromRoman(String romanChar)
{ 
if(romanchar==null){
return 0;
 }  
int i = 0;
int total = 0;    
 while (i < romanChar.length()) {
```

.

.
.
.